# Getting the Listview default clicked color, depending on the Device

Tags: android, listview, colors, default, device

In my android application, I use a listview and some linear layout on wich the user can click.

Of course, I had to set the background of my LinearLayout to a xml file where the stated pressed, selected are defined:

```
 myView.setBackgroundDrawable(
 getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background));
```

So no problem I set the drawable to transparent when normal use and orange when clicked.

My only problem is that on the galaxy S and some other customized phone (Sense UI) the color of the listview clicked is blue or green!

[image: http://img.skitch.com/20100928-fuq6ie4uxipguxug9yyinwher.jpg]    [image]

So I need to pick this color to set it to the background of my linearlayout.
I don't want to mix orange and blue, or orange and green for my user!

Where can I get this color???
That woule be really helpfull!

Comment: Why did you need to set the background of your listView?  If you don't do anything, the ListView will use the default color scheme.

Comment: I need to use it for LinearLayout that is at the top of the listview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the answer:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
```