# How to style view to look like a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the Listview default clicked color, depending on the Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817662/getting-the-listview-default-clicked-color-depending-on-the-device)

I would like to style a View to behave like a ListView. It means that when I click on it, the background color changes. I can't do this by setting a custom color because each device has a different style for this component. 
Any ideas how can I do it? Is there any system style I can apply on it?

Comment: I have a nice answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817662/getting-the-listview-default-clicked-color-depending-on-the-device/5640142#5640142

Comment: @Waza_Be that's the same thing as the answer here...

Answer (score 0):

```
setBackground(res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background));
```

Comment: I tested this on two devices (HTC DHD with 2.3 and HTC Sensation with 4.0) but they both have green background, although the second device has blue list items...

Comment: That's exactly the behavior you asked for. A standard ListView on these devices would look just like this

Comment: I don't think so. The new android has different styles for components. So the ListView is highlighted with blue, not green... Or maybe HTC has different styles that override the default ones...